# Update an object in nested array using Spring Data for MongoDB with arrayFilters

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a multi level document structure. For example,

```html
db.my_f.insert(
 {
  id_1: "id_1",
  list_1: [
   {
    id_11: "id_11",
    id_12: "id_12",
    list_2: [
     {
      id_31: "id_31",
      id_32: "id_32"
     },
     {
      id_31: "id_311",
      id_32: "id_321"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    id_11: "lot",
    id_12: "pot"
   },
  ]
 }
)
```

I want to edit element in List_2 using Spring Data. I believe it could be done using arrayFilters mentioned here 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831.

The problem is that this feature is implemented in com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions class, and I can't use it in org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations as i wanted to.

How could be implemented an operation to update element from List_2 using Spring Data and, probably, arrayFilters?